# How do I access double-nested arrays for multi-line chart in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've exhausted the extent of my logical capabilities in my multi-line chart trying to 1. add color, 2. add a tooltip, and 3. add mouseover animation to double-nested groups in d3.

Sample data:

```
state,year,lvalue,wvalue
GA,1980,0.8,value1
GA,1980,0.5,value2
GA,1981,0.3,value1
GA,1981,0.1,value2
```

Here's the group:

```
var nest = d3.groups(data, 
  d => d.state, d => d['lvalue'])
```

Where I'm currently running into issues with the colors and tooltip:

```
// Function to create the initial graph
  var initialGraph = function(legis){

    // Filter the data to include only state of interest
    var selectLegis = nest.filter(([key, ]) => key == legis)

      var selectLegisGroups = svg.selectAll(".legisGroups")
        .data(selectLegis, function(d){
          return d ? d.key : this.key;
        })
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "legisGroups")
        .attr('stroke', ([key, ]) => myColor(key))

    var initialPath = selectLegisGroups.selectAll(".line")
      .data(([, values]) => values)
      .enter()
      .append("path")

    initialPath
      .attr('d', (d) => valueLine(Array.from(d.values())[1]))
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .on('mouseover', function () {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .attr('stroke-width',3)
      })
      .on('mouseout', function () {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .attr('stroke-width',2)
      })
      .append('title') // Tooltip
      .text(function (d) { return d[1].state +
                           '\nlvalue: ' + d['lvalue']})
```

I've tried dozens of iterations for both and have had no luck and I can't seem to figure out how to properly pull what I need out of the arrays. I want the colors to be based off lvalue and the tooltips to show the state and lvalue.  Any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT: I've solved part of the problem, my CSS had attributes for the line class that were not being overridden, so I just created a different class (line2) not included in the CSS.

I still can't get the colors to separate and now the mouseover function applies to all of my lines regardless of the lvalue so I'm still not quite where I want to be.

Full code in case it's helpful:

```
  // Variables
  var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 }
  var h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom
  var w = 700 - margin.left - margin.right
  var formatYear = d3.format('d')
  var formatPercent = d3.format('.0%')

d3.csv('15/data3.csv').then(function (data) {

// format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.year = +d.year;
      d.state = d.state;
      d.wvalue = +d.wvalue;
      d["lvalue"] = d["lvalue"]
  });

// Scales
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0,w])
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([h,0])

  y.domain([
    d3.min([0,d3.min(data,function (d) { return d.wvalue })]),
    d3.max([0,d3.max(data,function (d) { return d.wvalue })])
    ]);
  x.domain([1968, 2016])
  
// Define the line
var valueLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.wvalue); })

// Create the svg canvas in the "d3block" div
var svg = d3.select("#d3block")
        .append("svg")
        .style("width", w + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
        .style("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px")
        .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "svg");

  //add reference lines
  svg.append('line')
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
    .attr("x1", x(1968))
    .attr("y1", y(0.08))
    .attr("x2", x(2016))
    .attr("y2", y(0.08))
    .attr("class", "line")

    svg.append('line')
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
    .attr("x1", x(1968))
    .attr("y1", y(0.00))
    .attr("x2", x(2016))
    .attr("y2", y(0.00))
    .attr("class", "line")

    svg.append('line')
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
    .attr("x1", x(1968))
    .attr("y1", y(-0.08))
    .attr("x2", x(2016))
    .attr("y2", y(-0.08))
    .attr("class", "line")

//nest variable
var nest = d3.groups(data, 
  d => d.state, d => d['lvalue'])

  var myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                    .domain(["lvalue1", "lvalue2", "lvalue3"])
                    .range(["#884E17", "#0D0FAD", "#0DAD1C"]);

  // X-axis
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat(formatYear)
    .tickValues([1968, 1972, 1976, 1980, 1984, 1988, 1992, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016])
  // Y-axis
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .tickFormat(formatPercent)
    .ticks(5)

    // Create a dropdown
    var legisMenu = d3.select("#legisDropdown")

    legisMenu
    .append("select")
    .selectAll("option")
        .data(nest)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", ([key, ]) => key)
        .text(([key, ]) => key)

  // Function to create the initial graph
  var initialGraph = function(legis){

    // Filter the data to include only state of interest
    var selectLegis = nest.filter(([key, ]) => key == legis)

      var selectLegisGroups = svg.selectAll(".legisGroups")
        .data(selectLegis, function(d){
          return d ? d.key : this.key;
        })
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "legisGroups")
        .attr('stroke', ([key, ]) => myColor(key))

    var initialPath = selectLegisGroups.selectAll(".line")
      .data(([, values]) => values)
      .enter()
      .append("path")

    initialPath
      .attr('d', (d) => valueLine(Array.from(d.values())[1]))
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .on('mouseover', function () {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .attr('stroke-width',3)
      })
      .on('mouseout', function () {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .attr('stroke-width',2)
      })
      .append('title') // Tooltip
      .text(function (d) { return d[1].state +
                           '\nlvalue: ' + d['lvalue']})

  }

  // Create initial graph
  initialGraph("Alabama")


  // Update the data
  var updateGraph = function(legis){

    // Filter the data to include only state of interest
    var selectLegis = nest.filter(([key, ]) => key == legis)

    // Select all of the grouped elements and update the data
      var selectLegisGroups = svg.selectAll(".legisGroups")
        .data(selectLegis)

        // Select all the lines and transition to new positions
            selectLegisGroups.selectAll("path.line")
               .data(([, values]) => values)
                .transition()
                  .duration(1000)
                  .attr("d", (d) => valueLine(Array.from(d.values())[1]))
  }

  // Run update function when dropdown selection changes
  legisMenu.on('change', function(){

    // Find which fruit was selected from the dropdown
    var selectedLegis = d3.select(this)
            .select("select")
            .property("value")

        // Run update function with the selected state
        updateGraph(selectedLegis)

    });
      
  // X-axis
  svg.append('g')
      .attr('class','axis')
      .attr('id','xAxis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + h + ')')
      .call(xAxis)
    .append('text') // X-axis Label
      .attr('id','xAxisLabel')
      .attr('fill','black')
      .attr('y',-10)
      .attr('x',w)
      .attr('dy','.71em')
      .style('text-anchor','end')
      .text('')
  // Y-axis
  svg.append('g')
      .attr('class','axis')
      .attr('id','yAxis')
      .call(yAxis)
    .append('text') // y-axis Label
      .attr('id', 'yAxisLabel')
      .attr('fill', 'black')
      .attr('transform','rotate(-90)')
      .attr('x',0)
      .attr('y',5)
      .attr('dy','.71em')
      .style('text-anchor','end')
      .text('wvalue')
})
```